# didUpdateValueForCharacteristic not called ios10

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

After discovering characteristics I have set notify yes to particular characteristic as below:

```
 [peripheral setNotifyValue:YES forCharacteristic:characteristic];
```

After this didUpdateNotificationStateForCharacteristic is called with notifying property as true but didUpdateValueForCharacteristic not called.Android people are getting values from device so there is no issue with hardware device.

Below is the whole code for ref:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
_centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];

// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central {
// You should test all scenarios
if (central.state != CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn) {
    return;
}

if (central.state == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn) {
    // Scan for devices
    [_centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:@{ CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey : @YES }];
    NSLog(@"Scanning started");
}
 }

- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI {

NSLog(@"Discovered %@ at %@", peripheral.name, RSSI);

if (_discoveredPeripheral != peripheral) {
    // Save a local copy of the peripheral, so CoreBluetooth doesn't get rid of it
    _discoveredPeripheral = peripheral;

    // And connect
    NSLog(@"Connecting to peripheral %@", peripheral);
    [_centralManager connectPeripheral:peripheral options:nil];
}
 }


 - (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didFailToConnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral error:(NSError *)error {
NSLog(@"Failed to connect");
[self cleanup];
 }

   - (void)cleanup {

// See if we are subscribed to a characteristic on the peripheral
if (_discoveredPeripheral.services != nil) {
    for (CBService *service in _discoveredPeripheral.services) {
        if (service.characteristics != nil) {
            for (CBCharacteristic *characteristic in service.characteristics) {

            }
        }
    }
}

[_centralManager cancelPeripheralConnection:_discoveredPeripheral];
}

 - (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didConnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral {
NSLog(@"Connected");

[_centralManager stopScan];
NSLog(@"Scanning stopped");
self.discoveredPeripheral = peripheral;

peripheral.delegate = self;

[peripheral discoverServices:@[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:SERVICE2_UUID]]];

 }

 - (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverServices:(NSError *)error {
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"Error discovering services: %@", [error localizedDescription]);

    return;
}

NSLog(@"services:%@",peripheral.services);

for (CBService *service in peripheral.services) {

    if([service.UUID  isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:SERVICE2_UUID] ])
    {
        [_discoveredPeripheral discoverCharacteristics:nil forService:service];
    }

}
// Discover other characteristics
 }

    - (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService:(CBService *)service error:(NSError *)error {
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"Error discovering characteristics: %@", [error localizedDescription]);        return;
}
NSLog(@"charac:%@",service.characteristics);

if([service.UUID  isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:SERVICE2_UUID] ]) {
    for (CBCharacteristic *characteristic in service.characteristics)
    {
        NSLog(@"loop if enetrred");
        NSLog(@"bool:%i",characteristic.isNotifying);

        if(characteristic.properties== CBCharacteristicPropertyIndicate) {

             [_discoveredPeripheral setNotifyValue:YES forCharacteristic:characteristic];
        }

    }



}
 }

 - (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didUpdateNotificationStateForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error{

if (error) {
    NSLog(@"Error changing notification state: %@ with charac:%@", error.localizedDescription,characteristic);
}

// Notification has started
if (characteristic.isNotifying) {
    NSLog(@"Notification began on %@", characteristic);

}
}

 - (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error {

NSLog(@"Characteristic value : %@ with ID %@", characteristic.value, characteristic.UUID);
NSLog(@"bool:%i",characteristic.isNotifying);
NSLog(@"char:%@",characteristic);
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"Error:%@",error.localizedDescription);

    return;
}



 }
```

Please help me to solve this issue..

Comment: the code looks correct, are you sure you are using the correct characteristic?

Comment: I am using correct characteristic ...In previous iOS versions I used to get values from hardware..for latest iOS version 10.2.1 not getting values..Is there any change in latest iOS version?

Comment: I don't think so.. have you tried the lightblue app, its a BLE app that lets you inspect characteristics and services for iOS.